# How to Iterate DStream in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark programming. I have a spark streaming program where it needs to store the received DStream into a database.I want to iterate my Dstream and store each record into Database.

something like this.

```
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = getSparkStreamingContext();

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> socketTextStream = streamingContext
                .socketTextStream("localhost", 8080);

DStream<String> dstream = socketTextStream.dstream();

// Iterate each record from the DStream and push it to DB
```

**Approach 2 :**

is tis correct way of doing ? any performance gain/issue will come with this approach?

```
socketTextStream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {

        List<String> collect = rdd.collect();

        for (String string : collect) {

            System.out.println(string);
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JavaDStream.foreachRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream) and [`JavaRDD.foreach`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD):

```
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = getSparkStreamingContext();
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> socketTextStream = streamingContext
        .socketTextStream("localhost", 8080);

socketTextStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) throws Exception {
                // Save data
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Or using Java 8 [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = getSparkStreamingContext();
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> socketTextStream = streamingContext
        .socketTextStream("localhost", 8080);

socketTextStream.foreachRDD((VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>) rdd -> {
    rdd.foreach((VoidFunction<String>) s -> {
        // Save data
    });
});
```

### Edit

Since you're using Spark 1.2.0 (which is a bit old, might I suggest upgrading (current latest is 1.6.1, as of 22/05/2016)):

```
socketTextStream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) throws Exception {
                // Save data
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ter is some syntax error . can you pls correct it ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.I'm using Java 7. and getting this error message.    The method foreachRDD(Function<JavaRDD<String>,Void>) in the type JavaDStream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>(){})

Comment: Why are you using `foreachRDD(Function<JavaRDD<String>,Void>)`? The signature for `foreachRDD` is: `def
foreachRDD(foreachFunc: VoidFunction[JavaRDD[T]]): Unit`, you should be using `new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>()`.

Comment: @BalajiReddy I'm not getting any compile time error with this code.

Comment: @BalajiReddy Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>

Comment: Awesome . It worked . I will upgrade my spark version too.  Thank you :)

Comment: can you pls look into my new approach and give me your comments ?